# Xuggle mp4 output (isom mp41 codec?) issues

Tags: ffmpeg, xuggle

We're using Xuggler to create an mp4 from pictures, with no audio at this point. The mp4 we're getting is playable locally, but cannot be embedded in a webpage or chromecast. I suspect the issue is that we're getting an older ISOM mp41 codec that's not supported by HTML5 and chromecast. That's a guess based on this snippet of header info:

```
Internet media type                      : video/mp4
Codec ID                                 : isom
Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
Codec ID/Url                             : 
http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/iso2/mp41
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec                                    : MPEG-4
Codec/Extensions usually used            : mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3ga 3gpa 
3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
```

I can embed and chromecast mp42 type files. So the first part of my question is Am I on the right track in looking at isom and mp41? And if so, can I get Xuggler to output using a newer codec?
I can post the full header if that would be helpful.
The above snippet is from mediainfo. Here's the whole thing, which is too long for a comment:
    General
    Count                                    : 325
    Count of stream of this kind             : 1
    Kind of stream                           : General
    Kind of stream                           : General
    Stream identifier                        : 0
    Inform                                   : MPEG-4 (Base Media): 377 KiB, 12 s 301 ms
    Count of video streams                   : 1
    Video_Format_List                        : MPEG-4 Visual
    Video_Format_WithHint_List               : MPEG-4 Visual
    Codecs Video                             : MPEG-4 Visual
    Complete name                            : C:\Users\Jon\Desktop\vid-1.mp4
    Folder name                              : C:\Users\Jon\Desktop
    File name                                : vid-1
    File extension                           : mp4
    Format                                   : MPEG-4
    Format                                   : MPEG-4
    Format/Extensions usually used           : mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
    Commercial name                          : MPEG-4
    Format profile                           : Base Media
    Internet media type                      : video/mp4
    Codec ID                                 : isom
    Codec ID                                 : isom (isom/iso2/mp41)
    Codec ID/Url                             : 
    http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/standalone.html
    CodecID_Compatible                       : isom/iso2/mp41
    Codec                                    : MPEG-4
    Codec                                    : MPEG-4
    Codec/Extensions usually used            : mov mp4 m4v m4a m4b m4p 3ga 3gpa 3gpp 3gp 3gpp2 3g2 k3g jpm jpx mqv ismv isma ismt f4a f4b f4v
    File size                                : 386063
    File size                                : 377 KiB
    File size                                : 377 KiB
    File size                                : 377 KiB
    File size                                : 377 KiB
    File size                                : 377.0 KiB
    Duration                                 : 12301
    Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
    Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
    Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
    Duration                                 : 00:00:12.301
    Duration                                 : 00:00:14:00
    Duration                                 : 00:00:12.301 (00:00:14:00)
    Overall bit rate mode                    : CBR
    Overall bit rate mode                    : Constant
    Overall bit rate                         : 251077
    Overall bit rate                         : 251 kb/s
    Frame rate                               : 3.415
    Frame rate                               : 3.415 FPS
    Frame count                              : 42
    Stream size                              : 1368
    Stream size                              : 1.34 KiB (0%)
    Stream size                              : 1 KiB
    Stream size                              : 1.3 KiB
    Stream size                              : 1.34 KiB
    Stream size                              : 1.336 KiB
    Stream size                              : 1.34 KiB (0%)
    Proportion of this stream                : 0.00354
    HeaderSize                               : 36
    DataSize                                 : 384703
    FooterSize                               : 1324
    IsStreamable                             : No
    File creation date                       : UTC 2017-05-05 19:49:25.209
    File creation date (local)               : 2017-05-05 15:49:25.209
    File last modification date              : UTC 2017-01-04 19:04:53.000
    File last modification date (local)      : 2017-01-04 15:04:53.000
    Writing application                      : Lavf54.3.100
    Writing application                      : Lavf54.3.100

```
Video

Count                                    : 338
Count of stream of this kind             : 1
Kind of stream                           : Video
Kind of stream                           : Video
Stream identifier                        : 0
StreamOrder                              : 0
Inform                                   : 250 kb/s, 200*200 (1.000), at 
3.415 FPS, MPEG-4 Visual (Simple@L1)
ID                                       : 1
ID                                       : 1
Format                                   : MPEG-4 Visual
Commercial name                          : MPEG-4 Visual
Format profile                           : Simple@L1
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, BVOP                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, QPel                    : No
Format settings, GMC                     : 0
Format settings, GMC                     : No warppoints
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Format settings, Matrix                  : Default (H.263)
Internet media type                      : video/MP4V-ES
Codec ID                                 : 20
Codec                                    : MPEG-4V
Codec                                    : MPEG-4 Visual
Codec/Family                             : MPEG-4V
Codec/CC                                 : 20
Codec profile                            : Simple@L1
Codec settings, Packet bitstream         : No
Codec settings, BVOP                     : No
Codec settings, QPel                     : No
Codec settings, GMC                      : 0
Codec settings, GMC                      : No warppoints
Codec settings, Matrix                   : Default (H.263)
Duration                                 : 12301
Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
Duration                                 : 12 s 301 ms
Duration                                 : 00:00:12.301
Duration                                 : 00:00:14:00
Duration                                 : 00:00:12.301 (00:00:14:00)
Bit rate mode                            : CBR
Bit rate mode                            : Constant
Bit rate                                 : 250207
Bit rate                                 : 250 kb/s
Width                                    : 200
Width                                    : 200 pixels
Height                                   : 200
Height                                   : 200 pixels
Sampled_Width                            : 200
Sampled_Height                           : 200
Pixel aspect ratio                       : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Display aspect ratio                     : 1.000
Rotation                                 : 0.000
Frame rate mode                          : VFR
Frame rate mode                          : Variable
Frame rate                               : 3.415
Frame rate                               : 3.415 FPS
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.333
Minimum frame rate                       : 3.333 FPS
Maximum frame rate                       : 65535.000
Maximum frame rate                       : 65 535.000 FPS
Frame count                              : 42
Resolution                               : 8
Resolution                               : 8 bits
Colorimetry                              : 4:2:0
Color space                              : YUV
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Chroma subsampling                       : 4:2:0
Bit depth                                : 8
Bit depth                                : 8 bits
Scan type                                : Progressive
Scan type                                : Progressive
Interlacement                            : PPF
Interlacement                            : Progressive
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Compression mode                         : Lossy
Bits/(Pixel*Frame)                       : 1.832
Stream size                              : 384695
Stream size                              : 376 KiB (100%)
Stream size                              : 376 KiB
Stream size                              : 376 KiB
Stream size                              : 376 KiB
Stream size                              : 375.7 KiB
Stream size                              : 376 KiB (100%)
Proportion of this stream                : 0.99646
Writing library                          : Lavc54.14.101
Writing library                          : Lavc54.14.101
```

Comment: Run mediainfo on the file and show its readout.

Comment: That's what the above snippet is, from mediainfo. I think that's the most relevant, but here's the whole thing:

Comment: Your codec should be MPEG-4/AVC. I believe MPEG-4 Part 2 is not supported.